# three/four column list with pop-up description below each item

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid-layout

I have a list of items, with each item having a (fixed size) **thumbnail image** and some **more data**. The list should now be displayed in a **three/four/X column layout**, with the thumbnail images being listed in rows.

When a thumbnail is clicked, there should be a (variable height) **pop-up with more data of the item below the thumbnail**, pushing the next row of thumbnails down. If another item in the same row is selected, the description should 'point to it'. If the item of another row is clicked, the currently opened description should collapse and the new description below the row of the newly selected item should appear.

Here is the **current version** (just look at the functionality, not the HTML structure): https://my.tado.com/webapp/#/compatibility-check/setup-selection/templates?installationProcessType=INSTALL_ST_G1
(if you select a 'setup template' and select a manufacturer on the next page, you see a four column variant of the list).

Now I want to redo the above so that the HTML structure ends up like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item--thumbnail">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="item--description>
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    ...
  </li>
</ul>
```

But the layout should look and behave the same. How could this be done? Maybe using **Flexbox** and its **source (re)ordering**?

The goal is to not have the grouping of items into rows present in the HTML and keep the description of items 'close to' the thumbnail.

Bonus points, if the solution is responsive so that there are **less columns on small screens**.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a go at cracking your problem and you can see my attempt here:

http://codepen.io/jefflau/pen/dYzZXj?editors=011

I've used React ES6, but it's not important to your solution, all it is doing is adding a 'selected' class to each `li.item` when clicked and only one `li` can have the selected class at a time so any others are removed.

*Note: I've removed the inner div for brevity, but you can add it back in. Apart from that I've used your exact html structure.*

It's not responsive, but I'm sure you could create a responsive solution to this, but the reason why I didn't is because I'm using a manually offset, which I'll explain later.

I've used `display: flex` and `flex-wrap: wrap` to create the rows.

**The interaction**

Every time a `item` gets the `selected` class it pushes everything down with a `margin-bottom` and then shows the inside `.item--description` div, which is `position: absolute` and is positioned `top: 100%` and `left: 0` from its parent.

Here is where the tricky part comes in. Since your box covers the entire row, I need to offset the `item--description` box so it sits relative to its parent. The way I am offsetting it is using `transform: translateX(px)`. The only elements that will be correctly positioning the 'description' box is the elements on the left hand side. To correct this I've used `nth-child` on the `li` assuming a 4 item layout and then manually adjusted every `transform: translateX()`

If you wanted to use this technique responsively, you could create media queries to deal with 3 and 2 column layouts etc...

I've also used a `:before` pseudo element to place a triangle relative to the position of the parent using `left: 50%` `top: 100%` and `transform: translateX(-50%)` to center it.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It is quite inspiring, I would have never thought of this approach! I also like how you did the triangle arrows. Unfortunately, I forgot to mention that the description div is of variable height and needs to scale with its content. I would also prefer to have less fixed sizes.

Comment: You could build the same thing with %s pretty easily. With the height of the container being variable, I can't think of a CSS only solution off the top of my head. It seems like the best option would to `onClick` measure the height of the description div and adjust the margin to match.